# Remove all linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm learning Java & Data structures.

I made a method that removes all the linked list. Here is the code:

```
public class LinkedList {
    ...
    public void purge() {
        SLLNode nextNode, iterator = headNode;

        while(iterator != null) {
            nextNode = iterator.getNext();
            iterator = null;
            iterator = nextNode;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the main method:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList test = new SinglyLinkedList();

        test.insert(1, 0); // insert(data, position)
        test.insert(2, 1);
        test.insert(3, 2);
        test.insert(4, 1);
        test.purge();
        test.printList(); // Still prints elements!
    }
}
```

So after all of insertion, the list is: 1-> 4 -> 2 -> 3, but the method purge() doesn't remove elements - the method printList() still prints the values in the linked list.  But I can purge the linked list like:

```
public void new_purge() {
    headNode = null;
}
```

But the purge() method doesn't look like have a problem.. probably it's lack of Java understanding, but why the method purge() doesn't work here?

Comment: Why you define LinkedList but you are instancing SinglyLinkedList?

Comment: @emecas Oops it is just copy & paste mistake lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning `headNode` to a local variable `SLLNode nextNode, iterator = headNode;` and then set it to null but your global (class instance) variable `headNode` is not affected.

As a side node, In Java, you should not worry about manual memory management in such cases as the Garbage Collector will free the memory. Assuming that the nodes are internally handled by the linked list class, setting the head to null is enough.

Comment: Ahhh I see! That's why headNode = null is enough in Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the problem is that you are overwriting your `iterator` pointer rather than the node's pointer. You are not actually affecting your nodes at all.

Your `new_purge` method should actually work and in fact is much faster (~n rather than ~2n).

Comment: I think `new_purge` is also O(n): the Garbage Collector needs to remove n objects anyway which is O(n). Though there may be one shot Garbage Collection for such cases.

Comment: OK. Well, then it's ~n rather than ~2n (in my extremely scientific notation)

Answer (score 2):

Small mistakes in your purge method.

```
 public void purge() {
    SLLNode nextNode, iterator = headNode;

    while(iterator != null) {
        nextNode = iterator.getNext();
        // iterator = null; -- does nothing.
        iterator.setNext(null); // You want to remove the pointer on the next element
        iterator = nextNode;
    }
    headNode = null; // Remember to clear also your head pointer.
}
```

But you should use LinkedList in the JAVA api.

Comment: Why iterator = null doesn't do anything?

Comment: Java Garbage collector (GC) removes object with no references. Setting to NULL a variable do not free the object.  You need to remove the reference pointing to this object (in this case iterator.setNext()).  Then, the GC will free up memory.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the method *purge()* could be more efficient regarding memory. It'd be:

```
public class LinkedList {
    ...
    public void purge() {
        SLLNode iterator = headNode;

        while(iterator != null) {
            iterator = null;
            iterator = iterator.getNext();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can remove the variable *nextNode*. And can you post your method *insert*?

Comment: You can't do this.  You have a nullPointerException on 2nd instruction.

Comment: And doing a method to put the data, for example setData(...data), and a loop while iterator not equal null and inside iterator.setData(null) and iterator = iterator.nextNode